# how can i do a "partition by" within a group based on a criteria?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

This seems straight forward, but I am having trouble figuring it out.  I have a table, where I am comparing records within a group (group_id).  I gave my records a flag based on certain criteria that was pertinent to my study. There are about 10 flags that I need to look at.  In some cases, within the group, only 1 record is flagged. In other cases, both records are flagged.

What I would like to do now is partition my group_id based on dates for each flag designation.  I have 3 time periods I'd like to look at: 2016, 2010 -2015, before 2010, and both records are the same.  These are reflected in my 'file_date' field which are not set up as a date type data. instead, they have an abcsum (summer) and abcwin (winter) designation, with the year.  In some cases this field is null.

What I would like to do is create another flag that the 'winner' of the partition would take based on which one of those date criteria was fit.  The importance of the criteria is from most recent to least recent.  Here is some sample data I hope will explain it further:

```
------------------------------
|group_id  | file_date | flag |
-------------------------------
| a        | abcsum16  | 3    |
| a        | abcwin16  |      |
| b        |  null     |  4   |
| b        | abcsum15  |  4   |
| c        | abcwin16  |  7   |
| c        | abcwin16  |  7   |
| d        | abcsum09  |  3   |
| d        | null      |      |
-------------------------------
```

The output would be:

---

```
|group_id  | file_date | flag | date_flag |
--------------------------------------------
| a        | abcsum16  | 3    |    1      |
| b        | abcsum15  |  4   |    2      |
| c        | abcwin16  |  7   |    0      |
| c        | abcwin16  |  7   |    0      |
| d        | abcsum09  |  3   |    3      |
-------------------------------------------
```

Comment: This is unclear. How did you assign values (0, 1, 2, 3) to the date_flag? There are three "classes" by date (2016, 2010-2016, and "until 2009). What does "both records are the same" and how does it affect the date_flag? And why did the rows with `flag=NULL` disappear from the output?

Comment: Sorry, the date flags are as follows: 1= in 2016, 2 = between 2010 and 2015, and 3 is anything > 2010;  in some cases, I have both records with the same 'file_date', these are the ones that would take a 0, as I cannot distinguish between the 2 dates.  The reason I didn't include the null fields are because I cannot use them; I suppose they can take a different flag code that signifies that they are null.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it. Please note, however, that it would (likely) be much better to use these techniques earlier in your process, if possible. For example, if `file_date` is not stored that way in your base table, but instead it is the result of some processing, it would be better to use the base data instead of the `file_date` expression. Also perhaps the analytic functions can be used sooner so you do fewer passes through the data (assuming, of course, that performance is important; sometimes it isn't).

```
with
     test_data ( group_id, file_date, flag ) as (
       select 'a', 'abcsum16', 3    from dual union all
       select 'a', 'abcwin16', null from dual union all
       select 'b', null      , 4    from dual union all
       select 'b', 'abcsum15', 4    from dual union all
       select 'c', 'abcwin16', 7    from dual union all
       select 'c', 'abcwin16', 7    from dual union all
       select 'd', 'abcsum09', 3    from dual union all
       select 'd', null      , null from dual
     )
-- end of test data (not part of the SQL query); query begins BELOW THIS LINE
select group_id, file_date, flag,
       case when count(*) over (partition by group_id) = 2
                 and
                 count(distinct file_date) over (partition by group_id) = 1 then 0 
            when to_number(substr(file_date, -2)) = 16                      then 1
            when to_number(substr(file_date, -2)) between 10 and 15         then 2
            else                                                                 3 end
                 as date_flag
from   test_data
where file_date is not null and flag is not null
;

GROUP_ID FILE_DATE FLAG  DATE_FLAG
-------- --------- ---- ----------
a        abcsum16     3          1
b        abcsum15     4          2
c        abcwin16     7          0
c        abcwin16     7          0
d        abcsum09     3          3

5 rows selected.
```